Can't get nginx to proxy guacamole
I have been trying to get nginx to reverse proxy gacamole, but was not very successful.
For this, over the past days, I have been following several howto's describing how to install nginx, guacamole and configure nginx to proxy the Tomcat 8080 port.
I have the feeling I'm almost there, but simply can't make the last step...
On an Ubuntu 22.04.05 LTS machine, I installed nginx and Tomcat9 out of the box. Next, I deleted the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file, and removed the symlink to that file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, and restarted nginx.
Then I installed guacamole (1.55, guacd and the webapp in tomcat). After having done this, I can get to the webapp from another machine using http://nginx-handbook.test:8080/guacamole. So, guacamole works.
Now for the proxying bit:
I created a file guacamole.conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d with the following content :
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name nginx-handbook.test;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/guac_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/guac_error.log;

  location = / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/guacamole;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    client_max_body_size 1g;
    access_log off;
  } 

}

Restarted nginx, and tried to go to guacamole from another server using http://nginx-handbook.test/ ,
but I'm getting a 404.
I know the proxy does work (sort of), because my actions are being logged in the proxy logs :
(guac_access.log)
192.168.56.1 - - [11/Sep/2024:16:07:38 +0000] "GET /guacamole/ HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
192.168.56.1 - - [11/Sep/2024:16:07:40 +0000] "GET /guacamole/ HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

(guac_error.log)
2024/09/11 16:07:38 [error] 29619#29619: *1 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/guacamole/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or 
directory), client: 192.168.56.1, server: nginx-handbook.test, request: "GET 
/guacamole/ HTTP/1.1", host: "nginx-handbook.test"
2024/09/11 16:07:40 [error] 29619#29619: *1 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/guacamole/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or 
directory), client: 192.168.56.1, server: nginx-handbook.test, request: "GET 
/guacamole/ HTTP/1.1", host: "nginx-handbook.test"

Although the error is quite clear (nginx is looking for guacamole in /usr/share/nginx/html), I don't quite understand. Was expecting to redirect to port 8080, and let Tomcat do the rest.
The /usr/share/nginx/html root is not set in any of the other nginx config files.
Should I set the root directive to point to /var/lib/tomcat/webapps ?
That was not documented anywhere in the howto's I've seen.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

With your configuration, when you make a request to http://nginx-handbook.test/, that shows up on the backend (tomcat) as:
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2024:22:59:14 +0000] "GET /guacamole HTTP/1.1" 302 -  

(That's from /var/log/tomcat9/localhost_access_log*txt.)
That returns the following response to the browser:
HTTP/1.1 302 
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 11 Sep 2024 23:01:12 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /guacamole/


So now your browser fetches http://nginx-handbook.test/guacamole/, which results in:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 11 Sep 2024 23:02:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

And, notably, that request does not show up in Tomcat's access log. That's because you're using = in your location directive:
  location = / {
    ...
  }

The = means "only match this block when the request is for /, and for nothing else". That means a request for anything other than http://nginx-handbook.text/ won't get proxied to the backend, and will result in messages like this in /var/log/nginx/guac_error.log:
2024/09/11 23:02:25 [error] 6472#6472: *12
"/usr/share/nginx/html/guacamole/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or
directory), client: 192.168.124.1, server: nginx-handbook.test, request: "GET
/guacamole/ HTTP/1.1", host: "guac.virt"

The solution is to remove the =:
  location / {
    ...
  }

That's one problem resolved! But now, a request for http://nginx-handbook.test/guacamole/ results in the following request in Tomcat's access log:
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2024:23:05:27 +0000] "GET /guacamoleguacamole/ HTTP/1.1" 404 783

What?
That's because you need to end the target path in your proxy_pass directive with a trailing /:
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/guacamole/;

Now, a request for http://nginx-handbook.test/ results in the following request in Tomcat's access log:
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2024:23:09:16 +0000] "GET /guacamole/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2811

Note that this no longer results in a redirect, because we're requesting /guacamole/ (which is where guacamole is hosted), rather than /quacamole. This allows everything to work, and the browser successfully loads the guacamole login page.

Thank you very much Larsks for your elaborate explanation.
Being used to working with apache2 still gives me trouble sometimes when working with nginx. E.g. I don't quite get why ending the proxy statement with a trailing / makes the request go from guacamoleguacamole to guacamole...
Anyhow, the solution works like a charm !
Thanks again.

Please consider marking this answer as accepted by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks!
